How to change color and the pagenumber color of the standout frame of metropolis beamer?
I want to change the background color of the standount frame in metropolis theme with \setbeamercolor{palette primary}{bg=cyan} after consulting the origin code(show as below) , but it turn out to be shown the original pagenumber.

My MWE is as below:
\documentclass{ctexbeamer}
\usepackage{lipsum,zhlipsum}
\usetheme{metropolis}
\setbeamercolor{palette primary}{bg=cyan}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{你好}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[standout]
    \frametitle{你好}
    \zihao{5}\lipsum[1]
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{你好}
    \lipsum[2]
\end{frame}
\end{document}


My question is:
(1) How to change the color of the page number in standout frame(the box shown above)? or just hide the page number?
(2) Is the command \setbeamercolor{palette primary}{bg=cyan} the Best Practice to change the color in standout frame?

You could drastically increase the number of people who can potentially help you if you make an example which does not need special fonts.

Ops, yes! I use the CJK fonts that might prevent some potential helper, thanks to you, I will keep that in mind!


(1) How to change the color of the page number in standout frame(the box shown above)? or just hide the page number?

You can add the plain option to the definition of the standout frame in order to hide the page number

(2) Is the command \setbeamercolor{palette primary}{bg=cyan} the Best Practice to change the color in standout frame?

If you'd like to also change the colour of frame titles etc., then changing the palette primary is fine. If you only want to change the background of the standout frame, you can do so in the definition of the standout frame
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usetheme{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme

\setbeamercolor{palette primary}{bg=cyan}

\makeatletter
\define@key{beamerframe}{standout}[true]{%
  \booltrue{moloch@standout}
  \begingroup
  \setkeys{beamerframe}{c}
  \setkeys{beamerframe}{plain}% <- new
  \setkeys{beamerframe}{noframenumbering}
  \setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=cyan}% <- new
  \usebeamercolor[fg]{palette primary}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{test}
  \lipsum[2]
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[standout]
  \frametitle{test}
  \lipsum[2]
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{test}
  \lipsum[2]
\end{frame}
\end{document}



Thanks for your excellent solution, and I also learn to know the fork of metropolis theme moloch, it helps me a lot!

@Explorer You're welcome!
